# How to extend nonlinear curve beyond supplied data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a plotted spectral curve in google sheets. All points are real coordinates. As you can see, data is not provided for the slope below 614nm. I would like to extend the slope beyond the supplied data, so that it reaches 0. In a mathematically relevant way to follow the trajectory it was taking from when the slope started. Someone mentioned to me I would have to potentially use a linear regression? I'm not sure what that is. How would I go about extending this slope relevant to it's defined trajectory down to 0 in google sheets?

[image]

Here's the data

```
x-axis:

614
616
618
620
622
624
626
628
630
632
634
636
638
640
642
644
646
648
650
652
654
656
658
660
662
664
666
668
670
672
674
676
678
680
682
684
686
688
690
692
694
696
698
700
702
704
706
708
710
712
714
716
718
720
722
724
726
728
730

y-axis:

0.7101
0.7863
0.8623
0.9345
1.0029
1.069
1.1317
1.1898
1.2424
1.289
1.3303
1.3667
1.3985
1.4261
1.4499
1.47
1.4867
1.5005
1.5118
1.5206
1.5273
1.532
1.5348
1.5359
1.5355
1.5336
1.5305
1.5263
1.5212
1.5151
1.5079
1.4994
1.4892
1.4771
1.4631
1.448
1.4332
1.4197
1.4088
1.4015
1.3965
1.3926
1.388
1.3813
1.3714
1.359
1.345
1.3305
1.3163
1.303
1.2904
1.2781
1.2656
1.2526
1.2387
1.2242
1.2091
1.1937
1.1782
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want The curve should be increased beyond the given data in a mathematically sound fashion until it approaches 0, In what follows, I'm going to show how it's done with the **last 2** data points which make the filled data **linear** it might help, like this: take a look at [this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EyRPiPmWLuf_4cahye-dZTrFxLEUUbq27seNRc9vaF4/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

We need to

1 - Paste this [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) function formula in `C3` to get the order of input

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B3:B),1,1,1)
```

2 - [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) the the input by pasting this formula in `E3`.

```
=SORT(A3:C61,3,0)
```

3 - In `F62` after the last line of the sorted data paste this [`TREND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094263?hl=en) function that Fits an ideal linear trend using the [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) approach to incomplete data about a linear trend and/or makes additional value predictions..

```
=TREND(F60:F61,E60:E61,E62:E101)
```

[`TREND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094263?hl=en) takes
'known_data_y' set to `F60:F61`
'[known_data_x]' set to `E61,E62` those are the **2 data point**
[known_data_x] set to `E62:E101`, we get it by pasting `E62:E101` after the last line of the sorted data in "x-axis:" in output table cell `E62`

4 - To see the newly genrated data in the red curve we need a new column that start from `K62` till the very bottom of the data "y-axis:" in output table cell `K62`, by pasting this [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) in `K62`.

```
=ArrayFormula(E62:G101)
```

5 - Add a Serie in tne chart in chart editor > setup > Series > Add Serie.